# Room livedata not correct

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I have this query in my DAO

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertFolders(folderList: List<Folder>)

@Query("select * from attachments_folders where companyId = :companyId")
fun getFoldersByCompanyId(companyId: Int): LiveData<List<Folder>>
```

I have this ViewModel

```
class FolderViewModel :ViewModel(){
private val folders: MutableLiveData<List<Folder>> by lazy {
    MutableLiveData<List<Folder>>().also {
        loadFolders()
    }
}

fun getFolders(): LiveData<List<Folder>> {
    return folders
}

private fun loadFolders() {
    FolderDao().getFoldersByCompanyId(Prefs.getInt(PreferenceKeys.COMPANY_ID, 0))
}
```

}

and then this in my activity

```
FolderViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(FolderViewModel.class);

model.getFolders().observe(this, new Observer<List<Folder>>() {
            @Override public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Folder> folders) {
                if(folders != null) {
                    if (folders.size() != 0) {
                        Fragment companyFragment = AttachmentsListFragmentFactory.newFolderAttachmentsFragment(new ArrayList<>(folders), getJobId());
                        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, companyFragment);
                        currentFragment = companyFragment;
                    } else {
                        Fragment companyFragment = AttachmentsListFragmentFactory.newCompanyAttachmentsFragment(false, getJobId());
                        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, companyFragment);
                        currentFragment = companyFragment;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

It keeps hitting the else block. There are 3 folders in the database. so i dont get why its doing that and if there is a way to rectify this because if there are folders in the db it should use the if fragment not the else one.

inserting folders

```
FolderDao().insertFolders(
                    Gson().fromJson<List<Folder>>(JsonHelper.getArraylistFromJson(response.body()?.string(), "folderList"),
                            object : TypeToken<List<Folder>>() {}.type))
```

EDIT: It seems that folders always seems to be null

Comment: Did you check `Prefs.getInt(PreferenceKeys.COMPANY_ID, 0)` return correct `companyId`?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman yes it does

Comment: @user3074140 can you please post the db table where the data is stored or can you post the code where you are inserting the data?

Comment: @RajSuvariya I have added that and i have also checked the database file and can see that the correct data is in there

Comment: @RajSuvariya It seems that the folders is always null it is not hitting the if else block

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here with the usage of `also`.

```
private val folders: MutableLiveData<List<Folder>> by lazy {
  MutableLiveData<List<Folder>>().also {
     loadFolders()
  }
}
```

Definition of `also`

```
public inline fun <T> T.also(block: (T) -> Unit): T {
  contract {
    callsInPlace(block, InvocationKind.EXACTLY_ONCE)
  }
  block(this)
  return this
}
```

As you can see, `loadFolders()` in *also* would not change anything. So you are not setting anything to the live data.

You should directly return

```
fun getFolders(): LiveData<List<Folder>> {
    return loadFolders()
}
```

Using `lazy` is probably not a right choice since you may want to change the folder id.

Comment: I was simply trying to follow the andorid doucmentation. I am not going to be changing the id only. Do i need to make load folders return something or assign to something? because doing you change with just lazy gives me a few errors.

Comment: A typeinference failure and a property delgate must have getValue() method error

Comment: I usually don't use `LiveData` to return something from Dao. so I am not sure if it will automatically publish the new data on database change.

Comment: What documentation are you following?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#kotlin